# Jquery tokeninput rails message

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to implement a messaging system among users.

Here the model of the database i am trying to implement.

```
user
  id

message
  message_id
  message_author_id
  timestamp

message_recipient
  message_id
  user_id

message_status
  message_status_id
  message_id
  user_id
  is_read
  is_deleted
  read_datetime
  deleted_datetime
```

The relationship would be I believe has follow

```
user
  has_many :messages
  has_many :message_recipient
  has_many :message_status

message
  has_many: user => author_id

message_recipient
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to user

message_status
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to :user
```

First i am not sure if the database is the correct way to implement has many recipients and not sure if its the proper rails way.

Second the goal is to implement jquery.tokeninputs, and therefore to my understanding i need to make sure that has many users will be able to take the author fields with many users.

Comment: you should split this into two questions. I'll try to answer the implementation part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your implementation, i think you may have a redundant model - depends on what you're trying to do, but it would go like this :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
  has_many :sent_messages, through: :messages 
  has_many :destined_messages, class_name: 'SentMessage'
end

# this class represents the original authored message,
# i.e. it holds the body of the message
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user # author
  has_many :sent_messages
end

# this class represents a "copy" of the message 
# that has been sent to a particular user. 
# It also holds the status, which makes sense because
# you want to log the status according to each user
class SentMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to :user
end
```

You can even merge the `Message` and `SentMessage` models if you don't care having duplicates : just make a copy of the body for each recipient.